# WSO2 ESB and WSAS cxf Rest Service - 404 status

Tags: cxf, wso2, jax-rs, wso2-esb

i'm new to WSO2 ESB. I installed the 4.7.0 version. I'm trying my first approach to RESTFul Web Services developed using CXF framework. I want to publish a first Hello World example. I downloaded and installed the WSO2 dev studio for eclipse Juno. 
I followed these steps:

1- New Project ---> Jax-RS Web service

2- i wrote the following class

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class servizio {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

    String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }
}
```

3- I saved and builded the War file by the wso2 function: Export this Project as a Deployable Archive

4- i entered the WSO2 app server GUI --> Applications ---> JAX-WS/JAX-RS ---> uploaded my war archive.

5- the WSO2 server notifies me that application was successfully uploaded and listed in the Applicatsions --> List menu 

6- when click on the "Find Service Link" i get HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available.

Even if i click on the WADL link i get the same 404 response: the links point to `http://MyHostIP:9763/progettServizio_1.0.0/services/servizio?_wadl`

IMPORTANT: If i install the same service on WSO2 application server 5.1, the service works fine... so i guess should be something wrong in the web application server activation on the ESB. I have done this by ---> Configuration ---> Features ---> Install Web Application Server.

Do i miss anything?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario and got the same error. Found out that this happens because cxf runtime dependencies are missing when you enable AS from features. Also this is going to be fixed in the next release.

For now, you can manually add the cxf dependencies to ESB. For that copy the `runtimes` folder from `<AS_HOME>/lib` to `<ESB_HOME>/lib` folder. Then restart your ESB.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing some class loading here pleaser refer [1]

Easiest way is to uSe WSO2 Developer studio to create your JAX-RS service please refer the documentation on [2].

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Webapp+ClassLoading

[2]. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/10/develop-cxf-based-jaxws-wso2-developer-studio

Thank You,
Dharshana.